# Simple non-web based bug tracker

Tags: python, windows, bug-tracking, non-web

There's a ton and and a half of questions and even more answers here concerning people looking for bug trackers. However all of them (that I found) seem to be about web based solutions. Since I'm working on a local project where I don't want to set up a web / DB server, and I don't want to use a hosted tracker either, I'm looking for something that runs locally.

- very preferably open-source
- pure Python or (at least) Windows executable
- no need for a database server (sqlite is obviously fine)
- Doesn't have to be fancy, just the basic bug / issue tracking functionality; just a little bit more than my current TODO text file or an Excel table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trac might be a bit too over engineered, but you could still run it locally via tracd on localhost.

It's:

- opensource.
- pure Python
- uses sqlite

But as I said, might be too complex for your use case.

Link: http://trac.edgewall.org

Comment: I have started to look into it a little bit. So far it seems I can just ignore those features that I don't need -- which is definitely not a standard property of bug trackers (bugzilla, anyone?)

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [Roundup](http://roundup.sourceforge.net/).

It meets all your criteria, including not requiring a web-based interface (as per your specification, and unlike the accepted answer which suggested Trac).

Roundup is:

- Open source
- Pure Python
- Supports SQLite
- Not fancy, focuses on solid bug tracking

And as a significant point of differentiation, it has command-line and email interfaces in addition to a web interface.

It's very easy to get started - I suggest you take it for a spin.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need to share your bug tracker system with a team (i.e., it's okay to have it isolated to your computer) I would recommend using [Tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/).  Technically it's web-based, but it's entirely encapsulated within a single HTML document and requires no database or server whatsoever (only a web browser) so I think it follows the spirit of what you are wanting.  It's extremely customizable since it's 100% HTML/CSS/javascript.  I have been using a tiddlywiki as a project notebook for years, keeping track of my to-do list, bug list, and general project documentation in one centralized, cross-referenced place.  You can also find all sorts of tiddlywikis that you can download pre-configured for productivity (for example, [TeamTasks](http://www.getteamtasks.com/), [MonkeyGTD](http://monkeygtd.tiddlyspot.com/), or [GTDTiddlyWiki Plus](http://www.checkettsweb.com/tw/gtd_tiddlywiki.htm)).

Comment: Interesting, that looks pretty neat. I'll take a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/) is of any use to you?

It is actually a DVCS but it also integrates a bugtracker and wiki, very much like trac (although I like trac, don't get me wrong). And its webbased, on the other hand the installation is supossedly dead simple.

Comment: Uses a web-browser, but doesn't require a dedicated web-server (just run `fossil ui`).  "Installation" is just copying a single file to your $PATH.  Also written by the same guy that gave us SQLite!

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary TestTrack (http://www.seapine.com/ttpro.html) has a client edition that will those things. We use it at work and I'm very happy using it.

Maybe you can check out this wikipedia article for hints 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems

Answer (score -13):

Do yourself a favor. Get over this "must not be web based" obsession, Install a local WAMP stack on your PC or on a LAN server. Now, you can install your own [wiki](http://lifehacker.com/software/wikipedia/geek-to-live-set-up-your-personal-wikipedia-163707.php). And something like Trac. I'd like to find an implementation of google code's bugtracker and integrated wiki thats runnable locally - [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDownload) seems to be the closest.

You have also installed a local SVN server? Even for personal projects the ability to track changes over time. revert etc. and integration with Trac are too good to pass up even for purely 1 man projects.

Comment: First, where do you get the "obsession" from? And second, why would I build a WAMP stack *and* install wikimedia *and* setup an SVN server before installing trac (which comes with a builtin webserver, uses sqlite and has a builtin wiki) and using Subversion (which doesn't need a server)? And yes, I do use source control from the very first line of code.